# Right way to convert serializer data to python dict

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm looking for a way to get the dictionary from the serialized data. I'm using that method now.

```
m = Mymodel.objects.all()
serializer = RfiParticipationCsvDownloadSerializer(m)
print(type(serializer)) # <class'apps.vendors.serializers.RfiParticipationCsvDownloadSerializer'>
qs = json.dumps(serializer.data)
print(type(qs)) # <class 'str'>
module_dict = json.loads(qs)
print(type(module_dict)) #<class 'dict'>
```

But I don't think it's the best or the right one. Tell me the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

serializer.data already has a ReturnDict type, so you can work with it like with a dict or you can copy serializer.data to a new dict if you need to change data because serializer.data is a property of the class and it is unmutable.

Answer (score 1):

serializer.data is ReturnList. ReturnList is a list of OrderedDict and we can cast OrderedDict to dict.
So the code would be like:

```
    all_objects = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer = MyModelSerializer(all_objects, many=True)
    serializer_return_list = serializer.data

    converted_data = []
    for ordered_dict in serializer_return_list:
        converted_data.append(dict(ordered_dict))

    print(json.dumps(converted_data))
```